# Binding a Generic list property to a Label Inside Datalist

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind Label to a Property of a Generic list inside Container.DataItem .

Here I am receiving a List in Container.DataItem want to go inside this Container.DataItem containing List.

Aspx code

`<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataBind %>'></asp:Label>`

Output :

```
System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Sizes]
```

C# Code :

```
List<List<Sizes>> Combosizes =new List<List<Sizes>>();

foreach (var i in skuIdsList)
 {
 var Sizes_list = (from item in sizes
 where item.SkuId == i.skuid
 select new Sizes
    {
     skusizeid = item.SkuSizeId,
     sizevalue = item.Sizevalue
    }).ToList();

   Combosizes.Add(Sizes_list);
 }

DataList3.DataSource = Combosizes;
DataList3.DataBind();
```

This is I have bind the List> to DataList3. And I am trying to bind the label inside the DataList3 with the first index of List of List.

Is there any solution.??

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<Sizes>> Combosizes =new List<List<Sizes>>();

foreach (var i in skuIdsList)
{
var Sizes_list = (from item in sizes
where item.SkuId == i.skuid
select new Sizes
{
skusizeid = item.SkuSizeId,
sizevalue = item.Sizevalue,
description = item.Description
}).ToList();

Combosizes.Add(Sizes_list);
}

DataList3.DataSource = Combosizes;
DataList3.DataBind();
```

You can bind value to the label at datalist item databound Event.

```
 protected void DataList3_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
var des = (List<Sizes>)(e.Item.DataItem);
Label lblsize = e.Item.FindControl("lblsize") as Label;
lblsize.Text = des.First().description;
}
```